# How to get status code of http response in angular?

Tags: angular, http, error-handling, http-response-codes

I want to show a toast that will have text depending upon the status code of the HTTP response.
code from service:-

```
private options = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders()
      .set("Content-Type", "application/json")
      .set("x-app-id", this.appId)
      .set("x-app-key", this.appKey)
      .set("observe","response")
  };
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
  search(query: string): Observable<{}>  {
    return this.http.post(this.url, {query: query}, this.options)
  }
```

and this is what I am doing in frontend:-

```
search() {
    this.showcard = false;
    this.isLoading = true;
    this.nutrix.search(this.searchValue).subscribe((res) => {
      if(res){
        this.isLoading = false;
        this.showcard = true;
        this.queryResult = res["foods"][0];
        this.imageUrl = this.queryResult['photo']['thumb']
      }
      console.log(this.queryResult);
    },(error) => {
      console.log(error);
      this.isLoading = false;
    });

  }
```

Comment: what you are getting `console.log(error);` in error callback, if you not status in that can you add that as well..

Comment: Found that status code there. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. I found that Arcteezy's solution doesn't work if I'm trying to distinct a 200 from a 201 response, for example. Also, I didn't want to use Interceptors, since my application was too simple. So I went other way.

As you can read on the HttpClient Documentation [here](https://angular.io/guide/http), there are optional options where you can ask for the full HttpResponse, instead of only the body. So I did that, and then was able to access the status code from response.status.

Here's a snippet of the code that worked for me:

```js
sendForm(data){
    return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
        this.http.post(this.url, data, { observe: 'response' }).subscribe(response => {
            if (response.status == 201) {
                resolve(response);
            } else {
                reject(response);
            }
        },err => {
            reject(err);
        })
    })
}
```

Bringing it back to the question, I figured what the problem might be.

In the documentation cited before, you can find that "*The types of the observe and response options are string unions, rather than plain strings.*"

this means you can't just pass a regular string, hence the "as const".
Also, I noted that you are setting the "observe" option inside the header, which is not the correct place to do so.

The options object should be as follows:

```js
private options = {
    observe: 'response' as const,
    headers: new HttpHeaders()
        .set("Content-Type", "application/json")
        .set("x-app-id", this.appId)
        .set("x-app-key", this.appKey)
};
```

This way, you are passing the correct options and is going to receive the entire HttpResponse, even in the success response.

Answer (score -1):

You can just call `error.status` from HttpErrorResponse.

```js
this.nutrix.search(this.searchValue).subscribe((res) => {
    // response
},(error) => {
    console.log(error.status);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

It`s better to use Error handling with interceptor

```
import {
 HttpEvent,
 HttpInterceptor,
 HttpHandler,
 HttpRequest,
 HttpResponse,
 HttpErrorResponse
} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { retry, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { ToastrService } from "ngx-toastr";
import { Router } from "@angular/router";

export class HttpErrorInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
constructor(private toastr: ToastrService, private router: Router) {}
 intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
   return next.handle(request)
     .pipe(
       retry(1),
       catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
         if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
      if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
        console.log("Error Event");
      } else {
        console.log(
          `error status : ${error.status} ${JSON.stringify(error.error)}`
        );
        switch (error.status) {
          case 401:
            this.router.navigateByUrl("/login");
            break;
          case 403:
            this.router.navigateByUrl("/unauthorized");
            break;
          case 0:
          case 400:
          case 405:
          case 406:
          case 409:
          case 500:
            this.handleAuthError(error);
            break;
        }
      }
    } else {
      console.error("something else happened");
    }

    return throwError(error);
       })
     )
 }
public handleAuthError(error: any) {
    console.log("error ", error);
    let msg = "";
    if (error !== undefined && typeof error === "string") {
      msg = error;
    } else if (error.error !== undefined && typeof error.error === "string") {
      msg = error.error;
    } else if (
      error.error.error !== undefined &&
      typeof error.error.error === "string"
    ) {
      msg = error.error.error;
    } else {
      msg = error.error.error.errors
        ? error.error.error.errors[0].errorMessage
        : "Something went wrong";
    }
    this.toastr.error(msg, "", {
      timeOut: 3000,
      positionClass: "toast-bottom-center",
    });
  }
}
```

add this tag in **app.module.ts**

```
providers: [
   {
     provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
     useClass: HttpErrorInterceptor,
     multi: true
   }
 ]
```